# neo4j: optional 'steps' in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find relations between nodes with optional but specific nodes/relationships in between (neo4j 2.0 M6).

In my data model, 'Gene' can be 'PARTOF' a 'Group. I have 'INTERACT' relationships between 'Gene'-'Gene', 'Gene'-'Group' and 'Group'-'Group' (red lines in model image).

I want to boil this down to all 'INTERACT' relationships between 'Gene': both direct `(Gene-INTERACT-Gene)` and via one or two 'Group' `(Gene-PARTOF-Group-INTERACT-Gene)`.

---

[image]

---

Of course this is easy with multiple Cypher queries:

```
# direct INTERACT
MATCH (g1:Gene)-[r:INTERACT]-(g2:Gene) RETURN g1, g2
# INTERACT via one Group
MATCH (g1:Gene)-[:PARTOF]-(gr:Group)-[r:INTERACT]-(g2:Gene) RETURN g1, g2
# INTERACT via two Group
MATCH (g1:Gene)-[:PARTOF]-(gr1:Group)-[r:INTERACT]-(gr2:Group)-[:PARTOF]-(g2:Gene)
RETURN g1, g2
```

But would it be possible to construct a single Cypher query that takes optional 'Group steps' in the path? So far I only used optional relationships and `shortestPaths`, but I have no idea if I can filter for one or two optional nodes in between two genes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a depth between zero and one for each of the relationships you add to the path. Try something like

```
MATCH (g1:Gene)-[:PARTOF*0..1]-(gr1)-[:INTERACT]-(gr2)-[:PARTOF*0..1]-(g2:Gene) 
RETURN g1,g2
```

and to see what the matched paths actually look like, just return the whole path

```
MATCH p=(g1:Gene)-[:PARTOF*0..1]-(gr1)-[:INTERACT]-(gr2)-[:PARTOF*0..1]-(g2:Gene) 
RETURN p
```

There is a bit of a bother with declaring node labels for the optional parts of this pattern, however, so this query assumes that genes are not part of anything other than groups, and that they only interact with groups and other genes. If a gene can have `[:PARTOF]` to something else, then `(gr1)` will bind that something, and the query is no longer reliable. Simply adding a where clause like

```
WHERE gr1:Group AND gr2:Group
```

excludes the case where the optional parts are not matched, so that won't work (it'd be like your third query). I'm sure it can be solved but if your actual model is not much more complex than what you describe in your question, this should.

I took the liberty of interpreting your model in a console [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/2iu6nw), check it out to see if it does what you want.

Comment: +10 for your Genes! This seems to be working. It's Friday afternoon though and I don't trust myself. Real life data is more complex, but I think I can handle the gr1/gr2 problem with filtering on properties that are true for both Gene and Group.

Comment: What I kind of don't get is HOW this matches 'Gene-PARTOF-Group-INTERACTS-Group-PARTOF-Gene' because the last step is INTERACT...

Comment: You're right, it is friday afternoon (and it doesn't match that case). The `[INTERACT]` in the middle should not be optional and the last relationship should be `[PARTOF*0..1]`, I think

Comment: This looks better, but I have to check it out. I think in order for this to work, Cypher needs to figure out WHICH nodes are optional, i.e. the opt1 right of g1 and the opt2 left of g2. See here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/om2nxt

Comment: More precisely, it 'uses' g1 as opt1/gr1 if there is no PARTOF between g1 and opt1/gr1. I don't get how Cypher computes this?

Comment: I agree it looks a bit funny when you return properties of the optional nodes and get those of the preceding non-optional ones, it looks like it matches twice. But I think this is a quirk of trying to make a tabular representation of a path. Maybe it ought to return an empty field as it does with the optional relationships when they are not matched (g1/gr1 doesnt actually have an untyped relationship to itself, in fact there is no gr1).

Comment: Good point, paths win. It seems to be working and I'll allow my brain to adjust to the logic behind this during the weekend.

Comment: But I think you're right, it binds both Gene Summers and his group to (gr1), which makes sense for traversal but is confusing if you expect that the other end of the [PARTOF] relationship will always be a group. I think that's why filtering on labels for (gr1) and (gr2) doesn't work–Gene Summers is not a group and so the optional relationship is no longer optional.

Comment: Great, I'll update my answer with the fix you pointed out for now

Comment: OK, one last comment: It looks like once you filter labels on gr1/gr2 the node becomes NOT optional. That is weird, it would be great to have real optional nodes.